# SQL - Avoid duplicates when self-joining a table

Tags: sql

I am currently trying to join a table to itself to determine differences in dates. The entries list attributes for different units that have a distinct ID. Every time the entry is edited, it adds a new entry with the new attributes, instead of rewriting it. I am trying to find all the entries where the start or end date are different. I am able to find all entries that the dates change, but I get duplicates displayed as such:
ID  StartDate1  EndDate1  StartDate2  EndDate2
1   1/12/2018  1/15/2018   1/13/2018   1/16/2018
1   1/13/2018  1/16/2018   1/12/2018   1/15/2018
 my code is the following:
 `SELECT DISTINCT u1.ID, u1.FirstNight, u1.LastNight, u2.FirstNight, u2.LastNight
FROM units u1
LEFT JOIN units u2 ON u2.ID = u1.ID
WHERE ((u1.firstnight <> u2.firstnight) AND (u1.lastnight <> u2.lastnight)`

What might I do to remove the duplicate entries?
 Thanks!

Comment: try `u1.firstnight < u2.firstnight` (instead of `<>`).

Comment: Maybe you van Use group by?

Comment: What do you need the differences for?  While you can't necessarily "just" use a `GROUP BY`, perhaps an aggregate is called for - getting the `MAX`/`MIN` for each value.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query meant to have

```
u2.ID != u1.ID
```

To stop each row joining to itself.

Change that condition to:

```
u2.ID < u1.ID
```

to also return only 1 version of each pair.

Comment: I think you haven't understand @Teddy Miller's question, give special attention to this `Every time the entry is edited, it adds a new entry with the new attributes, instead of rewriting it`, and with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

There is no a simple solution for  what you want to do. You must play a little with the values of the fields to achieve the desired result.

Try this SQL code

## Schema

```
create table dates (id int, first date, last date);

insert into dates (id, first, last) VALUES (1, '2018/03/11', '2018/5/11');
insert into dates (id, first, last) VALUES (1, '2018/08/11', '2018/10/11');
insert into dates (id, first, last) VALUES (1, '2018/03/25', '2018/09/16');
insert into dates (id, first, last) VALUES (1, '2018/02/25', '2018/04/16');

insert into dates (id, first, last) VALUES (2, '2018/05/10', '2018/08/09');
insert into dates (id, first, last) VALUES (2, '2018/09/15', '2018/07/18');
```

## Query

```
SELECT id1, first1, last1, id2, first2, last2 FROM 
(

    SELECT distinct 

    d1.id id1, 
    d1.first first1, 
    d1.last last1, 
    d2.id id2, 
    d2.first first2, 
    d2.last last2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (d1.first + d2.first)) rn

    FROM dates d1
    JOIN dates d2 ON d2.id = d1.id

    WHERE (d1.first <> d2.first) AND (d1.last <> d2.last)

) AS DataResult

WHERE rn = 1;
```

#### How it works

- The subquery select the desired fields,
- but the last field use an Aggregate Window Functions with the ROW_NUMBER() function.
- This last, count all element partitioned by the Sum of the First Dates in self joined table
- The outside query select the desired fields less the Row Number field, besides use the Row Number calculated to restrict to 1 in the Where clause.

Here are a [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cLgZKbzJnfnyBv58t7nanc/0) to test a bit more!